# How can I run a 6.5V-100V power meter on 5V?

Tags: power, dc, buck, boost, meter

I have an [eBay power meter](https://www.ebay.com/itm/100A-DC-Digital-Watt-KWH-Current-Power-Energy-Meter-Ammeter-Voltmeter-7-100V-US-/281768704865) (V/A/W/Wh) that is specced between DC 6.5V and 100V. It's wired with a 75mV 100A shunt, like this:

[image]

If I wanted to run the thing at 5 volts what would be the easiest way? There's an 3.3V linear regulator on the board (Z1) so I assume the logic runs fine on less than 6.5V. I haven't checked what the LCD backlight runs on, but I guess it would be fine on 5 volts.

My first thought was to remove D1 (1N4007) which has a 1 V forward voltage drop and replace with a short, but I'd rather keep the reverse protection. What would be the easiest way to convert this to run on 5V? On 5V it doesn't even power on. When I connect it to a 12V supply it runs fine, except the readings (other than current) would obviously be off.

Here's a picture of the circuit board. U2 is the LCD controller. Z1 is a 3.3V linear regulator. Also the 2 points marked "W" read 3.15 volts. Other components I haven't checked.

Edit: U3 is a chip marked MXM11P62 and I could only find a [Chinese datasheet](http://www.mixchips.com/datasheet/MXM11P62%E7%9B%B4%E6%B5%81%E7%94%B5%E8%83%BD%E8%AE%A1%E9%87%8F%E5%BA%94%E7%94%A8%E7%AC%94%E8%AE%B0%20v0.pdf) and here is a [Google translation](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mixchips.com%2Fdatasheet%2FMXM11P62%25E7%259B%25B4%25E6%25B5%2581%25E7%2594%25B5%25E8%2583%25BD%25E8%25AE%25A1%25E9%2587%258F%25E5%25BA%2594%25E7%2594%25A8%25E7%25AC%2594%25E8%25AE%25B0%2520v0.pdf)

[image]

Thanks for the answers...

Comment: for 5V get one of the USB power meters instead.

Comment: If you just temporarily bypass D1, does it work at 5V?

Comment: @hekete the screen shows some values very faintly but I can't read. The backlight doesnt come on.

Answer (score 2):

for 5V operation you'll need to loose the diode D1 and THE voltage regulator formed by 
R3 R4 R5 R7 Z2 C13 Q1 
and feed the apropriate voltage (probably 5v) to the Q1 terminal closest to E4
probably best to measure that first.

you can get some reverse polarity protectopn by putting a reversed diode in parallel with the input. but if you have a 100A 5V supply that won't work well.

Comment: Q1 drain reads 12V when connected to 12V are you sure that's a voltage regulator? (Though it might be regulating to 12V, I don't know the component values and I dont have an adjustable supply to test)

Comment: It's a voltage regulator, maybe it only starts regulating at 12V input, and perhaps Z1 a the second voltage regulator, perhaps AMS1117 producing 3.3 to run the microcontroller

Comment: yeah Z1 is a 3.3V regulator

Comment: would the readings still be accurate if I separated the voltage reading from the supply for the circuit, if I took off the voltage regulator you mentioned and instead gave 12V using a boost converter?

Comment: they should be. I would expect the voltage-sensing pick-off to be up-stream of D1: it looks like R6,R10,R11 could be the voltage divider that accepts the supply voltage and converts it down to something acceptable to the ADC.

Comment: Can you get the data sheet on Q1? It may be possible to just change some of those resistor values to do what you want...

Answer (score 1):

So this is what the input stage looks like from your picture (assuming there is nothing on the back):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3rbZa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Q1 is a power N-MOS ([FQD2N60C](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FQU2N60C-D.PDF)). Its Gate is connected in series with 120kOhms from V+ and the Drain is connected in series with 20Ohms from V+.

Z2 is some sort of fuse or diode or diode fuse? Given it's marked as Z I would guess it's a Zener diode acting as a fuse/regulator. It's probably not active in the voltage range you're using...

Then we have an inductor L1, with the E3 and E4 on each side (not sure what those are). The Z1 which you said is a regulator seems to have V+ going in the GND pin? I'm guessing there is a GND connection on the other trace which goes to the IN pin.

So, my wild guess at this point is that those via's past E4 go on to power the LCD/back-light. Probably at around 5V. With a 5V supply there must be too much of a drop to run the back-light properly. The minimum voltage from the spec is 6.5, which even after the diode drop is still 5.5V. I think your best  solution at this point would be to boost your 5V input. The circuit wouldn't take up much space and you could make it part of one end of the cable.

Here is something to try though. We know you get 12V out of M1 with 12V input. So it should be safe to connect your 5V input directly to the output of M1. That bypasses all the regulation and voltage losses of that input stage. I'm thinking it probably still wont work, but it's easy to try.

Comment: Q1 reads "7X28 FQD 2N60C" on it and according to Google it's a N channel MOSFET,  and the drain (large tab) measures 12 V when connected to a 12 V source

Comment: Hmm okay I wasn't expecting a MOSFET. Z1 is a 3.3V regulator, do you have a link to its data sheet? Do you know what E3 and E4 are? I can also see a bunch of vias connected to one side of E4, can you see where they go or is the LCD covering the other side?

Comment: Check smd coding 513=51kohm, 100=10ohm ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a source-follower pre-regulator followed by your 3.3V regulator.

If you just jumper source to drain on the MOSFET it may work well enough at 5V.